# How to shuffle sections of data in a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains the pixel values of document images. The data mentioned between Begin & End tags consist of a unique id, the ground truth value and the feature vector for each line of the document image. However, I want to shuffle **the sections of data as units**. Can anybody point out a method as to how I can randomize or shuffle this data?

```
===Begin==

TAG:0014/7_21

TRUTH:0020 0915 0941 091b 0020 0927 0940 092e 0940 0020 092a 095c 0940 0020 092a 0930 , 0020 092f 0939 093e 0901 0020 0909 0938 0947 0020 0905 0928 0947 

FEATURE:14 32 256 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

===End==

===Begin==

TAG:0014/7_16

TRUTH:0020 0925 093e 0020 0914 0930 0020 091a 093e 0939 0924 093e 0020 0925 093e 0020 0915 093f 0020 0906 091c 0020 0915 0947 0020 091c 092e 093e 0928 

FEATURE:19 32 43  1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

===END===
...
...
```

and so on.

I need to shuffle the entire content between the BEGIN and END tags.

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of shuffling do you want? All the characters between the Begin/End tags, which would mess up the `TAG`, `TRUTH`, and `FEATURE` headings, or the values in all three lines, or the values in just `TRUTH` and `FEATURE`, or something else? And have you checked the [shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) function in the `random` module?

Comment: Let's call the text delimited by your ===BEGIN=== and ===END=== markers a section. Do you want to shuffle the contents of each section, or do you want to keep their contents intact and shuffle the sections as units?

Comment: yes exactly @PM2Ring ,I want to keep their contents intact and shuffle the sections as units

Comment: You can use `random.shuffle()` from the standard library to shuffle. It's quite straighforward. If you need specific help, you should include your python code, not just the input data. [mcve]

Comment: I just noticed that your markers aren't uniform. Some of them end in `==` but the final one ends in `===`, and the last one is all upper-case but the others aren't. Splitting the data into sections would be slightly simpler (& more efficient) if the markers were uniform, eg `===Begin===` and `===End===`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the section delimiters are supposed to be uniform, and the variations in the delimiters in the data given in the question are typos.

Shuffling the sections is easy, once we split the data into sections. I've created some fake data with 5 sections to illustrate the process.

```
src = '''\
===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_29

TRUTH:019e 0078 02fc 0790 0552 0d01 0f8a 0f67 06d7 0cd5

FEATURE:229 81 20 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_06

TRUTH:0a09 01d4 019a 0f41 0509 01d1 0290 05f2 0231 022c

FEATURE:214 97 4 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_05

TRUTH:0ea1 0a1e 0252 004c 0eaa 0333 0258 06d2 087c 043d

FEATURE:25 15 153 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

===End===


===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_01

TRUTH:08b7 0904 06bd 0af8 0683 0872 0fa2 0809 01a0 02f4

FEATURE:178 101 78 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

===End===
===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_19

TRUTH:04bd 0dc0 0414 0156 09dd 0bab 0146 0b73 06b8 07fc

FEATURE:202 74 248 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0

===End===
'''

from random import seed, shuffle

# seed randomizer so we can get reproducible results
seed(42)

# Split data into sections
data = []
section = []
src_lines = iter(src.splitlines(True))
for line in src_lines:
    section.append(line)
    if line.startswith('===End==='):
        data.append(section)
        section = []
        # Skip any extra blank lines between sections
        for line in src_lines:
            if line and not line.isspace():
                section.append(line)
                break

shuffle(data)
for sec in data:
    print(''.join(sec))
```

**output**

```
===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_01

TRUTH:08b7 0904 06bd 0af8 0683 0872 0fa2 0809 01a0 02f4

FEATURE:178 101 78 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_06

TRUTH:0a09 01d4 019a 0f41 0509 01d1 0290 05f2 0231 022c

FEATURE:214 97 4 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_05

TRUTH:0ea1 0a1e 0252 004c 0eaa 0333 0258 06d2 087c 043d

FEATURE:25 15 153 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_19

TRUTH:04bd 0dc0 0414 0156 09dd 0bab 0146 0b73 06b8 07fc

FEATURE:202 74 248 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0

===End===

===Begin===

TAG:0014/7_29

TRUTH:019e 0078 02fc 0790 0552 0d01 0f8a 0f67 06d7 0cd5

FEATURE:229 81 20 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

===End===
```

The line

```
src_lines = iter(src.splitlines(True))
```

allows us to iterate over the lines in the `src` string as if we were iterating over the lines in a file. To use this code on an actual file instead, replace that line with

```
with open(filename) as src_lines:
```

and indent the `for line in src_lines:` block so that it's inside the `with` block.